# Undownloadable Software Package

Tags: cygwin

During the latest months, the following Software Package is undownloadable from the mirrors that I have tried.

Does anybody know what to do in order to fix this issue?

The `Cygwin` Software Installation usually finishes, but not in a perfect way (with a null exit status).

[image: Undownloadable Software Package]

[image: Download Error]

[image: Installation Error]

[image: Final Exit Code, although not related to the Missing Software Package]

Comment: I assume you have tried to update your repository sources?

Comment: Why didn't you ask on the cygwin mailing list? => https://cygwin.com/lists.html -> "cygwin" or even the IRC-channel => https://cygwin.com/irc.html

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried several mirrors. I have not found the `js-mathjax-2.6.1-1.tar.xz` Software Package anywhere.

Comment: @Hannu True. True. I shall look at their Mailing List.

Comment: @Hannu I have tried five times to send them an Electronic Mail Message, but their Filtering Robot is difficult to avoid.

Comment: do not use HTML message. See guidance on https://www.cygwin.com/ml/

Comment: Related: https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/

Comment: @matzeri - It is much eviler than that. I guess that System Administering may simply become inhuman. Check this paragraph out: _If you have tried all of the above techniques and are still unable to send email to a mailing list, then send email to the postmaster at this site. Be prepared to be mocked, if any of the above needs to be repeated to you, however._

Comment: @Ramhound - Still, the word _Cygwin_ does not appear on that Web-Page.

Comment: So? It was still applicable to your situation to the fact your downloading an older release.  Anyways: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: @Ramhound - I am not interested in the Latest Release of that Software Package. I just want to perform a Full Software Installation of the `Cygwin` Environment. I do not intend to debug this Issue. I was just curious whether anybody else has stumbled upon it.

Comment: To be able to send an email to a mailing list, you must first JOIN it.

Comment: @Hannu - True. True. I have been there. I have done that. Somehow, the Electronic Mail Address must have been Black-Listed. I should contact their System Administrators, but I do not want to go further than that. I just wanted a simple check whether anybody knows anything about this issue, not to troubleshoot the whole `Cygwin` Environment.

Answer (score 0):

This Issue has been solved by itself, as it is usually happening these days.

The idea to discuss this Issue with the Administrators and with the Moderators of the `Cygwin` Mailing List might have led to an Instructive Experience. However, I have not asked anybody else anything related to the possible causes of this Issue.

I can imagine that the `Cygwin` Environment has been updated in the meantime. The Software Package that was nowhere to be found must have been correctly added to the Installation Scripts. No Issue is now raised regarding the Downloading Process.

The Full Software Installation of the `Cygwin` Environment now finishes almost perfectly. I am getting a known error that I was getting *before* encountering this Issue that is described in this Question.

```
Package: _/Unknown package
x3270.sh exit code 1
```

[image]

I can imagine that this kind of errors may appear in time when the Software Installation gets a little bit corrupted.

Anyway, I would like to thank everybody for their interest in this Issue.

I can recommend the following pieces of advice to anyone who might ever get interested in performing a Full Software Installation of the `Cygwin` Environment, which Size is greater than 100 GigaBytes:

1. Dedicate a Software Partition for the whole `C:\CygWin\` Folder that contains the actual Software Installation.
2. Dedicate a Software Partition for the whole `C:\CygWinKit\` Folder where the Downloaded Software Packages reside.
3. Since there is no Uninstallation Procedure for the `Cygwin` Environment, one may easily wipe out everything from the Partition where the `C:\Cygwin\` Folder that contains the actual Software Installation resides and then may go on to cleanly reinstall everything in the same place.

**Update:** (12-March-2018)

I am happy to report that I have been able to find a solution for the last error message at the following Uniform Resource Locator:

[Last Error Message](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-04/msg00106.html)

Kenneth Wolcott writes:

> Every time I update the 64-bit Cygwin the following happens:
>
> Package: _/Unknown package
>
> ```
> x3270.sh exit code 1
> ```
>
> Just curious, is this an obsolete/orphaned package?

Neither.  You seem to have had that package installed at one time, but
then either the /etc/setup/x3270.lst.gz file went missing or the
uninstall didn't clean up the post-install script for whatever reason.
If you just want to get rid of that message, simply remove

/etc/postinstall/x3270.sh

If you want to clean up everything, install the package x3270, then
remove the packages x3270 and suite3270.  I'm assuming that you have
other packages that will still need libopenssl100, libX11_6, and libXaw7.
If not, then you could remove those, too.

Regards,

Achim.